How to integrate this differential equation??
I encountered a differential equation while proving energy conservation in physics but was unable to integrate it.
$\frac{dv}{dt}=pv-qv^2t$
Here $p,q \in R$
I tried converting it to linear form of differential equation but was unable to do so. Any help is appreciated!!

It's a Bernoulli equation. See here how to solve it.

You are on the right track. The given ODE can indeed be reduced to a linear one by dividing both sides by $v^2$ since $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dv}\left(-\frac1{v}\right)=\frac1{v^2}$:
$$\frac{\mathrm dv}{v^2\mathrm dt}-\frac{p}{v}=-qt$$
Substituting $k=-\frac1{v}$, we get:
$$\frac{\mathrm dk}{\mathrm dt}+pk=-qt$$
You can take it from here.
P.S. As the comment by @Gonçalo has stated, such ODEs are termed as Bernoulli DEs which can be made linear by dividing both sides by a suitable power of the dependent variable:
$$y'+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
$$\implies (1-n)\frac{\mathrm d(y^{1-n})}{\mathrm dx}+P(x)y^{1-n}=Q(x)$$
